# How to write a custom override for LabelFor in asp mvc 2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, label, strongly-typed-helper

Hi I have a piece of code which gives an error.

```
<%=Html.LabelFor(m => m.Id, new { @Class = "textbox-medium" })%>
```

Error:

No overload for method 'LabelFor' takes '2' arguments.

Does anyone know how to resolve this ?

Thanks

Comment: Possible Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5131021/337294

Comment: This is not a duplicate. that question is really about an issue with compilation and matching an existing overload of LabelFor. the solution to this question is an entirely new overload of LabelFor. @Darin's answer is brilliant because it explains how to properly utilize LabelFor's use of Linq Expressions and metadata. It is only unfortunate that the question was not better articulated, although the title convey's most of the information needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe something among the lines:

```
public static class LabelExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString LabelFor<TModel, TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> ex,
        object htmlAttributes
    )
    {
        var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression<TModel, TProperty>(ex, htmlHelper.ViewData);
        var htmlFieldName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(ex);
        var labelText = metadata.DisplayName;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(labelText))
        {
            labelText = htmlFieldName.Split('.').Last();
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(labelText))
        {
            return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
        }

        var tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("label");
        var id = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(htmlFieldName);
        tagBuilder.Attributes.Add("for", id);
        var attributes = new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes);
        tagBuilder.MergeAttributes(attributes);
        tagBuilder.SetInnerText(labelText);
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
    }
}
```

and then:

```
<%= Html.LabelFor(x => x.Id, new { @class = "textbox-medium" }) %>
```